Creating new conda environment offline from tar.gz file
I have an offline device, and I want to transfer an entire conda environment onto that device. I created the environment on an online device, and then transferred it via a tar.gz file to the offline machine. I then ran tar -xzf transfer_env.tar.gz -C transfer_env. This seemed to work fine, and I was able to activate the environment conda activate transfer_env. However, when I tried running jupyter notebook, I got a huge error. I'm not sure how I can fix this, because I have ipykernel, jupyter, and nb_conda_kernels installed on the environment. When I run where python, I get C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs\transer_env\python.exe, which seems fine (I.e. within the environment). What's going wrong with Jupyter notebook?
Here's the error:
Failed to run command:
    ['D:\\bld\\ipykernel_1719845595208\\_h_env\\python.exe', '-m', 'ipykernel_launcher', '-f', 'C:\\Users\\my_user\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-d65a656a-77ed-4349-8cec-7aa12beb4955.json']

[E 2024-10-21 10:29:12.679 ServerApp] [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs\transfer_env\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 87, in wrapper
        out = await method(self, *args, **kwargs)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs\transfer_env\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 439, in _async_start_kernel
        await self._async_launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
      File "C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs\transfer_env\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 354, in _async_launch_kernel
        connection_info = await self.provisioner.launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs\transfer_env\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\provisioning\local_provisioner.py", line 210, in launch_kernel
        self.process = launch_kernel(cmd, **scrubbed_kwargs)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs\transfer_env\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 170, in launch_kernel
        raise ex
      File "C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs\transfer_env\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 155, in launch_kernel
        proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)  # noqa
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs\transfer_env\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
        self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs\transfer_env\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs\transfer_env\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1790, in _execute
        result = await result
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs\transfer_env\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\auth\decorator.py", line 73, in inner
        return await out
               ^^^^^^^^^
      File "C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs\transfer_env\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 108, in post
        raise web.HTTPError(500, str(e)) from e
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 500: Internal Server Error ([WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified)
[E 2024-10-21 10:29:12.821 ServerApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8888",
      "Accept": "*/*",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/tree/Project/Notebooks/TRANSFER_ENV",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
    }
[E 2024-10-21 10:29:12.821 ServerApp] 500 POST /api/sessions?1729502952612 (06092a48e7ce4843995c6bc813925ade@::1) 187.15ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree/Project/Notebooks/TRANSFER_ENV



It looks like the startup command for the ipython kernel has a file reference that is hard-coded for the particular environment location.  I don't think you are going to have luck trying to copy an entire environment.
What you can do, it copy the index cache, copy the package .tar.bz2/.conda files, and create an environment spec file (yaml) for you environment.  Then you can move all of those things to the new computer along with a copy of miniconda.
Install miniconda, then use the conda version in miniconda to create the environment in offline mode using your already downloaded cache and files.
Overview
(NOTE: this install instructions are for Windows; for linux, use cp instead of copy and flip the backslashes to forward.)
Steps:

Create a directory to pack all of your files into:

mkdir envpack


Get miniconda from: Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe
Move the installer to your packing directory:

mv path\to\downloads\Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe  envpack


Clear your conda cache (this is to make transferring the package file a reasonable size) using:

conda clean -a -y


Create the environment you want to have a clone of (this will download the package and index files):

conda create -n myenv python jupyter pandas -y


Create a YAML file with the environment spec:

conda env export -n myenv > envpack\myenv.yaml


Copy the index cache folder and package files to packing directory:

see next section


Move the envpack directory to a portable media, transfer to new device, and install miniconda.
Copy files to miniconda's pkgs_dirs directory.

see final section


Run conda install for local setup.

Copying the index cache and package archives
Conda downloads the repodata.json files for each channel you use to an index cache.  It also downloads the package .tar.bz2 or .conda files before installing them as well.  The location of these is the first directory returned by:
conda config --show pkgs_dirs

Example output:
pkgs_dirs:
  - C:\Users\James\miniconda3\pkgs   <--- this is the location we need.
  - C:\Users\James\.conda\pkgs
  - C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs

Since we cleared the cache in step 3, only the packages that were downloaded in step 4 will have tarball or conda archive files (other directories still exist).

Create a sub-folder for the packages

mkdir envpack\pkgs


Copy the archive files (replace C:\Users\James\miniconda3\pkgs with the pkgs_dirs line):

copy C:\Users\James\miniconda3\pkgs\*.conda  envpack\pkgs
copy C:\Users\James\miniconda3\pkgs\*.tar.bz2  envpack\pkgs


Create a cache subfolder and copy the files in the following folder:

mkdir envpack\pkgs\cache
copy C:\Users\James\miniconda3\pkgs\cache envpack\pkgs\cache



Off-line install
For step 7, I assume you have a method to copy the files to a USB drive (or whatever media), and can transfer it to the offline device.  I am going to use Z:\envpack to refer to the location of the files on the portable media.

Install miniconda how you like from the z:\envpack\Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe.
After installation, check the location that conda uses for package cache:

conda config --show pkgs_dirs
typically it is something like: C:\Users\username\miniconda3\pkgs


Copy all archive files and the index cache to that location.

copy Z:\envpack\*.conda C:\Users\username\miniconda3\pkgs
copy Z:\envpack\*.tar.bz2 C:\Users\username\miniconda3\pkgs
mkdir C:\Users\username\miniconda3\pkgs\cache (may already exist)
copy Z:\envpack\cache C:\Users\username\miniconda3\pkgs\cache


Create the environment using the spec:

conda env create --use-index-cache --offline --file Z:\envpack\myenv.yaml -n myenv




Thanks for the comment. When I'm installing miniconda on the offline device, I get a prompt asking: 'Register Miniconda3 as my default Python 3.12'. I already have some existing environments on the offline device and I don't want to mess anything or create any conflicts. Will this cause an issue? Do I need to have miniconda3 in the pkgs_dirs on the offline machine for this to work?

No, you don't need to register miniconda as your default Python application.  And no, you don't need to put the miniconda installer in the pkgs_dirs.
